# File is not writing using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, soap, file-io, io, fileoutputstream

I have Java Desktop Swing application in which I am trying to write XML file, but it's not writing data into file. Here my code is:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(input_file);
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapcall, url);
String str = WebServiceDAO.soapMessageToString(soapResponse);
System.err.println("String*****" + str);
fileOutputStream.write(str.getBytes());
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Here I am getting data but its not writing in file. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try using `flush()`

fileOutputStream.write(str.getBytes());
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();

Comment: I tried that but its not working @Pphoenix

Comment: Do you get any errors or is the file just not written?

Comment: I dont get error just file is not written.. :(

Comment: Maybe your application does not have rights to write into this file?

Comment: i guess before writing you need to open the file and may be rights

Comment: @vikeng21 and how can i do that?

Comment: @wawek its sould be then how could i rewoke it?

Comment: Are you sure that you get a response for your SOAP request? Try this  soapResponse.writeTo(System.out) before writing to file and see if you get any output.

Comment: @Guneli even i am getting all response of soap and i am printting that into the console and each data is coming correct.

Comment: I think your path for input_file is not showed correctly. Are you sure that such a path and such a file exists in your system? Cause I tried your code on my machine and it worked.

Comment: @Guneli i am trying to give full path okey and let u know :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your filePath is not resolving to a valid location. Try the below code which creates parent folders for you.

```
String input_file = "D:/Temp/Sample/abc.txt" //whatever path you are using
File file = new File(input_file);
File parent_directory = file.getParentFile();
if (parent_directory != null) {
  parent_directory.mkdirs();
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: I am trying this only.

Comment: Yes that is right just proper location was not going but how could i make it dynamic i mean if i have file in same folder then how could i give path?

Comment: If you give the same file name it will overwrite existing file. But you can construct the fileName dynamically. You can append the timestamp to the fileName, say HHmmss. So in the above example fileName would be like abc_143025.txt. If you want the file name to be same, you can construct a folder dynamically. So the file path would be D:/Temp/Sample/143025/abc.txt. You can try out a similar logic

Comment: i am asking about if that file is already created then how u will access that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write XML file as like this also

public String xmlFileWriter(String cfile, String Listname, String Nodename , String nodevalue) {

```
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File(cfile);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        log.info("xml root element selected :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(Listname);



        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            log.info("xml top level 1 element selected :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                log.info("xml top level 2 element selected :" + Nodename);
                log.info("xml top level 2 element new value :" + nodevalue);

                eElement.getElementsByTagName(Nodename).item(0).setTextContent(nodevalue);
                log.info("After calling setattribute :" + eElement.getElementsByTagName(Nodename).item(0).getTextContent());
            }
        }

        /* to save xml file  begin */

        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
        Result xmlresult = new StreamResult(fXmlFile);
        Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
     //   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("outFoFile.fo");
     //   transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlFile), new StreamResult(fos));
        xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "UTF-8");
       xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        xformer.transform(source, xmlresult);
        result2 = "Success";
        /* to save xml file  end */


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e.toString());
        result2 = "Faild";
    }

    return result2;

}
```

Comment: if i wanted to write in this way i never preferred fileoutputstream okey i need to run that code only.

Comment: you can write it as string then why you are writing as bytes

Comment: i have used that in whole project so its cant be changed for single thing